# At which points does the graph of the $f(x)$ have horizontal tangent line?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$(2x^2-2x-1)/(x^4+1)$

I tried to solve with the derivative method. But came across a fifth degree Polynomial involving $5$ terms. After that my math failed to factorize it. This is the derivative $2x^5 - 3x^4-2x^3-2x+1$. Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried using the rational root theorem?

Comment: Try it again. It does have a rational root.

Comment: @GerryMyerson is it possible if I put x=0 and solve the derivative for y intercept in order to find the horizontal tangent line

Comment: No, that doesn't make much sense. You've been shown that your fifth degree polynomial has the rational root $x=-1$, so that's one place where there's a horizontal tangent. Factoring out $x+1$ leaves you with a fourth degree polynomial, which has no rational root. If my calculations are correct, it doesn't factor as a product of two quadratics, so it's an irreducible fourth degree polynomial. That leaves you two choices: numerical methods, or the Quartic Formula. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With derivative method, we get
$$f'(x) = \frac{(4x-2)(x^4+1)-4x^3(2x^2-2x-1)}{(x^4+1)^2} = 0.$$
We have to find $x$ so that the equality can be fulfilled.
We obtain
$$(4x-2)(x^4+1) - 4x^3(2x^2-2x-1) = 0$$
$$ \iff (4x^5-2x^4 + 4x-2)- 8x^5+8x^4+4x^3 = 0 $$
$$\iff -4x^5 + 6x^4+4x^3+4x-2 = 0 $$
$$\iff 2x^5 - 3x^4 -2x^3-2x+1 = 0.$$
Define $g(x) = 2x^5 - 3x^4 -2x^3-2x+1$.

If you substitute $x = -1$, then $g(-1) = 0$. So $(x+1)$ is the factor of $g(x)$.
We get
$$g(x) = (x+1)(2x^4-5x^3+3x^2-3x+1).$$

From this equation, we obtain at $x=-1$, $f(x)$ has a horizontal tangent line.
You can find 2 more solution (if I'm not mistaken).

**Hint:** Find $x$ as a solution of $2x^4-5x^3+3x^2-3x+1 = 0.$

Comment: Those 2 more roots are the real problem i came across some newton method for them but that is way higher than my level.

Comment: How do you propose that OP solve that fourth degree equation, Niccolo? If I'm not mistaken, the polynomial is irreducible over the rationals.